# SQL - Join Three tables with different columns

Tags: sql

I have 3 Tables; ( I want to join tables)

Table A;

```
Name    countLemon
-----   ----------
UserA   5
UserB   3
UserC   2
```

Table B;

```
Name    countApple
-----   ----------
UserA   1
UserB   8
```

Table C;

```
Name    countOrion
-----   ----------
UserA   3
UserC   9
```

I need a query which will give:

```
Name    countLemon  countApple  countOrion
-----   ----------  ----------  ----------
UserA   5           1           3
UserB   3           8           0
UserC   2           0           9
```

Comment: Where does your current code fall short of achieving what you want?

Comment: Can someone explain why or in which way this is opinion-based ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `left join`:

```
select a.name, a.countLemon, coalesce(b.countApple, 0) as countApple,
       coalesce(c.countOrion, 0) as countOrion
from a left join
     b
     on b.name = a.name left join
     c
     on c.name = a.name;
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that. That's bcz the answer's only explanation is to strain every nerve for the expansion of some reputation point.